# Regex optional capturing group?

Tags: regex, option-type, capturing-group

After hours of searching I decided to ask this question. Why doesn't this regular expression `^(dog).+?(cat)?` work as I think it should work (i.e. capture the first dog and cat if there is any)? What am I missing here?

```
dog, cat
dog, dog, cat
dog, dog, dog
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The reason that you do not get an optional `cat` after a reluctantly-qualified `.+?` is that it is both optional and non-anchored: the engine is not forced to make that match, because it can legally treat the `cat` as the "tail" of the `.+?` sequence.

If you anchor the cat at the end of the string, i.e. use `^(dog).+?(cat)?$`, you would get a match, though:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(dog).+?(cat)?$");
for (String s : new String[] {"dog, cat", "dog, dog, cat", "dog, dog, dog"}) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)+" "+m.group(2));
    }
}
```

This prints ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/sgeL1Z))

```
dog cat
dog cat
dog null
```

> Do you happen to know how to deal with it in case there's something after cat?

You can deal with it by constructing a trickier expression that matches anything except `cat`, like this:

```
^(dog)(?:[^c]|c[^a]|ca[^t])+(cat)?
```

Now the `cat` could happen anywhere in the string without an anchor ([demo 2](http://ideone.com/IuJ786)).

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know how to deal with it in case there's something after cat? For example: `dog, dog, cat, blah`. I want to capture only first dog and optional cat (there can be at most one cat).

Comment: would love to see this answer

Answer (score 17):

Without any particular order, other options to match such patterns are:

### Method 1

With non-capturing groups:

```
^(?:dog(?:, |$))+(?:cat)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/yCQLRo/1/)

Or with capturing groups:

```
^(dog(?:, |$))+(cat)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/R0rceo/1/)

---

### Method 2

With lookarounds,

```
(?<=^|, )dog|cat(?=$|,)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/vuqhmv/1/)

With word boundaries,

```
(?<=^|, )\b(?:dog|cat)\b(?=$|,)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/tAQOP5/1/)

---

### Method 3

If we would have had only one `cat` and no `dog` in the string, then

```
^(?:dog(?:, |$))*(?:cat)?$
```

would have been an option too.

#### [RegEx Demo 5](https://regex101.com/r/Pnu4Bd/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^(?:dog(?:, |$))*(?:cat)?$";
        final String string = "cat\n"
             + "dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, dog, dog\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, cat\n"
             + "dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog\n";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: cat
Full match: dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, dog
Full match: dog, dog, dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, dog, dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, dog, dog, dog
Full match: dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, cat
Full match: dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Pnu4Bd/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Pnu4Bd/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

@dasblinkenlight's answer is great, but here's a regexp that improves the 2nd part of it, when he/she's asked

> Do you happen to know how to deal with it in case there's something after cat?

The regexp `^(dog)(.+(cat))?` would require you to capture group no. 3 instead of 2 to get the optional cat, but works just as well without the char-by-char trickery.

And here's [the demo](http://ideone.com/gEswoZ) (which, again, is forked from @dasblinkenlight's demo which allowed me to tinker and find this solution, thanks again!)

Comment: Also works with a non-capturing group like ^(dog)(?:.+(cat))? so you don't have an extra capturing group in there

Answer (score 3):

@figha's extension can be extended slightly further still, to not make the unnecessary second capture.

Use `?:` to make a bracketed part of a regex non-capturable. So the regex becomes: `^(dog)(?:.+(cat))?`

Again, here's the [extended demo](http://ideone.com/LWwt6v) and the [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/ROkKFb/2).